# Windows Universal app crashes after Associating identity with Store

Tags: windows, cordova, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm creating a cordova app for Windows.

Now when I build this normally (with my own identity of which I have no clue where he gets it from) everything works fine and my app launches with success.

Although when I then associate my app with the Store, and have my actual app name + package name etc filled in for me, I get a blank screen when trying to run my app.

The `head` and `body` tags stay empty and no error is thrown in my JavaScript console.

Any idea of why this happens? The problem definitely is that I associate my app with the Store and then something happens which makes my app crash or fail to start. 
But why does it do this? And how can I resolve it?

(currently building with VS2017)

**edit**
Alright, so I figured out that because the package name changed, I had to edit that as well in the manifest. Now My main root component is loaded, but it isn't setting the `app root` to any page, just a blank screen. (with a menu that can open on swipe).

Comment: Can you please look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46783140/6078071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so my Microsoft assigned package name was different than my own. This caused the app to look for my own package name instead of the Microsoft one I associated with.

The solution was quite simple, just set your `widget-id` in your `config.xml` to the Microsoft assigned package name and rebuild your solution.

(I was using Ionic framework so re-execute `ionic build windows --release --prod --arch="arm"`)