# UWP app crashes after associating with the store

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I'm creating a cordova app for Windows.
After associating the app with the store the application start page goes white blank.
The app works fine if it uses the package identity name com.something.moretext
but my store package identity name is 58661Something.MoreText

the windows store package identity name starts with numbers so i get error of unmatched pattern if i change widget-id  manually in config.xml and rebuild it.

If i just change in the visual studio without running the command (cordova build windows) i get no error but the application still comes as blank white screen.
Please suggest

[Screenshot][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly213.png

Comment: Could you provide details of the error, like a screenshot?

Comment: There is no error comes in the error log but when i launch the application in the phone it just show plain white blank screen.

Comment: Have you tried using Visual Studio to build the package, instead of using Cordova build command?

Comment: Yes i did that .. thats how i am associating my app with the store. Cordova build command i use for building it. but i create packages via the option: Store>Associate with the store> Then Create app packages

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve this problem by changing the Applications StartPage value in manifest same as the package identity name .
for e.g i changed StartPage="ms-appx-web://com.something.moretext/www/index.html"
to StartPage="ms-appx-web://58661something1.moretext1/www/index.html"

Comment: Didn't worked for me.. I used camera plugin. Now it's showing me error as 'Windows' is undefined.